# getValue from BehaviorSubject in Angular component

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I want to try to make a comparison in my component by using
   if(success) displayMessage
   else redirectToPage in 3 seconds.
But, how can I check this ***(this.link$.source.value.success) or (this.link$.getValue()) *** if it send NULL. I try display in my console browser this.link$, it's display the BehaivorSubject. I try with a method getValue() it's not work. Can you please help me.

Thanks again

**Browser console.log**

[image]

**Service.ts**

```
  private objectRes: BehaviorSubject<ResModel>;
  public activationOrResetResponse: Observable<ResModel>

  constructor(
    public _apiService: ApiService,
  ) {
    super(_apiService);

    this.objectRes = new BehaviorSubject(null) as BehaviorSubject<ResModel>;
    this.activationOrResetResponse = this.objectRes.asObservable();
  }

  public activateOrResetAccount(token: string, typeRoute: string): void {
    this._apiService.get(this.type + "/" + typeRoute + "/" + token).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.activationOrReset = res;
        this.objectRes.next(this.activationOrReset);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.activationOrReset = error;
        this.objectRes.next(this.activationOrReset);
      }
    );
  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
  public link$: Observable<ResModel>;
  constructor(
    private _authUserService: AuthUserService,
    private _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getActivationPage();
  }

  public getActivationPage(): void {
    this.link$ = this._authUserService.activationOrResetResponse;
    this._authUserService.activateOrResetAccount(
      this._activeRoute.snapshot.params.token,
      "confirmation"
    );
    console.log("link$: ", this.link$.getValue());   // null ???????
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`value`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L19) getter is part of `BehaviorSubject()`, not the corresponding observable. So you need to assign the `BehaviorSubject()` instead of the observable to use it. Try the following

```js
public getActivationPage(): void {
  this.link$ = this._authUserService.objectRes;  // <-- assign the `BehaviorSubject`
  this._authUserService.activateOrResetAccount(
    this._activeRoute.snapshot.params.token,
    "confirmation"
  );
  console.log("link$: ", this.link$.value);   // `value` instead of `getValue()`
}
```

And it won't work because the variable is private in the service.

I'd add that this doesn't look very elegant. Now there are two unnecessary copies of the `BehaviorSubject`. Better way would be to write a getter in the service. The `link$` variable looks redundant to me.

Service

```
private objectRes: BehaviorSubject<ResModel>;
public activationOrResetResponse: Observable<ResModel>

constructor(public _apiService: ApiService) {
  super(_apiService);

  this.objectRes = new BehaviorSubject(null) as BehaviorSubject<ResModel>;
  this.activationOrResetResponse = this.objectRes.asObservable();
}

get activationValue(): ResModel {
  return this.objectRes.value;
}
```

Component

```
  public getActivationPage(): void {
    this._authUserService.activateOrResetAccount(
      this._activeRoute.snapshot.params.token,
      "confirmation"
    );
    console.log("link$: ", this._authUserService.activationValue());
  }
```

**Update**

The correct way would be do the following

Component

```js
  ngOnit() {
    this.getActivationPage();
    this._authUserService.activationOrResetResponse.subscribe(
      response => { console.log(response); }
    );
  }

  public getActivationPage(): void {
    this._authUserService.activateOrResetAccount(
      this._activeRoute.snapshot.params.token,
      "confirmation"
    );
  }
```

Comment: I change a variable private by public and change the code, but it's not work again, I have NULL in concole, why?

Comment: Because `activateOrResetAccount()` in the service is an asynchronous function. By the time the `console.log()` is processed the value hasn't been pushed to the `BehaviorSubject`. See here to learn more about asynchronous requests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921. That is reason for using a `BehaviorSubject` in the first place. Use `value` is a undercutting it, and it won't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I see, I try put setTimeout and it's work, I change my service in async await, thank's again :)

Comment: `setTimeout()` is also a work around in this context. The correct way would be to subscribe to the observable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you getting your initial value and need to skip it till get a response from your server.

```js
public getActivationPage(): void {
  this.link$ = this._authUserService.activationOrResetResponse;
  this._authUserService.activateOrResetAccount(
    this._activeRoute.snapshot.params.token,
    "confirmation"
  );

  this.link$
  .pipe( 
     skipWhile((value) => !value), // skip null values
     take(1) // if you need the value only once
  )
  .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));  // { "sucess": false, "message": "Bad action link!" }
```

Comment: @ValentynSHCHERBOV I edited the example, please check it again.